# Application gets stuck when trying to change text of label dynamically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code, that I call when a page is loaded:

```
public StartPage()
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Scan_Function();
    });
}
```

In `Scan_Function()`, I have a stopwatch and a bunch of if-statements, that are supposed to make the text of `bleText` label change dynamically:

```
public void Scan_Function()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    while (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= 10000)
    {   
        if (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds >= 1000 && sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= 1050)
        {
                bleText.Text = "Scanning.";
        }
        else if (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds >= 2000 && sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= 2050)
        {
                bleText.Text = "Scanning..";
        }
      ....... continues 
    }
        sw.Stop();
        bleText.Text = "Couldn't connect";
        bleText.TextColor = Color.Red;
}
```

I'm calling my Scan_Function() from `Task.Run()`, because I want the method to run asynchronously with everything else so that the user can still press buttons etc.

My problem is though, that nothing happens! I'm suspecting that something is wrong with `bleText.Text`, cause my debugger reaches it and seems to get stuck without updating anything or jumping out of the loop.
If i comment my if-statements, it runs through the loop, but get stuck once it reaches `bleText.Text` outside the loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# in Async Task change Label Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281387/c-sharp-in-async-task-change-label-text)

Comment: Why don't you use a timer? `Stopwatch` isn't a timer or even an "active" class. It stores the processor tick value when `Start` is called and uses it to calculate a duration when `Elapsed` is called. In any case you just *can't* update the UI from another thread, no matter the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update the UI from a background thread.  Use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` to force your code to execute on the UI thread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
    bleText.Text = "Couldn't connect";
    bleText.TextColor = Color.Red;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I encapsulate the entire while loop in this, or would i just do it for the label?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen why don't you use a timer? All this code should be deleted. No loop, no blocking the task, no task to begin with. If you really want to use a loop, use `await Task.Delay()`, not Task.Run

Comment: it's not possible to await within a non-async method though